# How to download attachments in .eml file?

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, eml

I have an .eml file which contains .eml files as attachements and each of these files have an pdf attachment, how do I download the pdf files from every email file?

Attaching the email file components

[image: image of email as attachments]

[image: Image containing the pdf attachements]

tried using python email parser module

```
msg = email.message_from_file(open('AWEX WMR.eml'), policy=policy.default)

for att in msg.iter_attachments():
    print(att)
```

This is returning the following content

> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text
> editor Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="WMR.pdf"
> Content-Description: WMR.pdf Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="WMR.pdf"; size=271839;  creation-date="Wed, 09 Nov 2022
> 07:52:34 GMT";    modification-date="Wed, 23 Nov 2022 08:56:38 GMT"
> Content-ID:
> 38E40A850A94904CB726DA820FF407EC@INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Still Unable to download the file

Comment: Could you share your existing code?

Answer (score 3):

On PyPI there is an existing package called `eml-extractor` which should be the thing you're looking for.
You can find it here: [eml-extractor](https://pypi.org/project/eml-extractor/)
,or just use  `pip install eml-extractor`.

Usage: eml-extractor [OPTIONS]

```
Extracts attachments from .eml files

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s PATH, --source PATH
                        the directory containing the .eml files to extract
                        attachments (default: current working directory)
  -r, --recursive       allow recursive search for .eml files under SOURCE
                        directory
  -f FILE [FILE ...], --files FILE [FILE ...]
                        specify an .eml file or a list of .eml files to extract
                        attachments
  -d PATH, --destination PATH
                        the directory to extract attachments to (default:
                        current working directory)
```

Just the command `$ eml-extractor` already searches for all `.eml` files in your working directory and saves the attachments in the same directory. Further specifications are really easy to achieve.

Hope this helps!